# Gwart "still giving most of her money to Rand Paul"?

Tags: silicon-valley

In Silicon Valley S06E06, at 8:42, Jared mentions that he's no longer thinking about Gwart, whether she's hungry, cold, or "still giving most of her money to Rand Paul."

Gwart is obviously a bizzare character, who never speaks, but is there any significant link between Gwart and Rand Paul? Or was this just a random reference?

Comment: I didn't like Gwart either but she might play a important role in the final episode, lets wait until Sunday :)

Comment: @ashveli did OP say they don't like Gwart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://www.politico.com/story/2015/12/silicon-valley-tech-rand-paul-216687) on Rand Paul's some investment in Silicon Valley and I guess Jared's reference points to this. Maybe he is against Rand Paul's (in universe) investments in Silicon Valley.

Gwart giving money to Rand Paul's campaign is subjected to more facts.

So what he's trying to say is, he is not at all concerned about Gwart's actions anymore.